# Cписок с подклассами TypeVar("V") как возвращаемый тип для метода

Tags: python, наследование, typing, mypy

Есть абстрактный класс:

```
class Parent(Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self) -> List[T]:  ...
```

Мне нужно создать абстрактный подкласс, который в методе `test` будет возвращать список с подклассами `V` (Например `[Cls1, Cls2, Cls3, ...]`):

```
V = TypeVar("V")


class Child(Parent[V]):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self) -> List[V]: ...
```

Чтобы в последствии я мог конкретизировать, подклассы какого типа будет возвращать `test`:

```
class IntChild(Child[int]):  # test должен возвращать список подклассов int
```

**Что я пробовал:**

Если в `bound` передавать `type`, то `V` будет обозначен как класс-наследник `type` (т.е метакласс), что мне не подходит

Если в `Child.test` написать `def test(self) -> List[Type[V]]: ...`, то типы метода не совпадают с родительскими (В `Child` `List[Type[V]]`, а в `Parent` `List[V]`), что тоже не хорошо:

```
error: Return type "list[type[V]]" of "test" incompatible with return type "list[V]" in supertype "Parent"  [override]
```

**Вопрос:** Как указать, что метод `test` в `Child` должен возвращать не список объектов типа `V`, а список подклассов `V`

Comment: Как я понял вам надо менять либо в родительком классе `List[T]` на `List[type[T]]`, либо `IntChild(Child[int])` менять на `IntChild(Child[type[int]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вам надо возвращать тип type[V], а не V. Так что же вам мешает указать его?

```py
class IntChild(Child[type[int]]): ...
```

Для примера ЭТО у меня не вызывает предупреждений:

```py
class IntType(int):
    pass


class IntChild(Child[type[int]]):
    def test(self) -> List[type[int]]:
        return [int, IntType]
```